# Public DNS (IPv4) on alibaba

Tags: cloud, alibaba-cloud

When I tried the free aws account, I have used the Public DNS to test my website (something like http://ec2-10-1-127.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/).

How can I get that using alibaba cloud ?

I found out this [Link](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/essential-guide-to-alibaba-cloud-domain-name-system-dns_593751), but I didn't know how to get the public dns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alibaba Cloud Free trial ECS provides you with a public IP address. You can directly enter this IP in the browser to access your ECS instance. And if a web server like Nginx or Apache already running on the ECS instance and listening on port 80, you will be able to access your website.

BTW, Alicloud ECS does not provide FQDN as AWS does.